# Android recording call using NDK

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, audiorecord, call-recording

I was very tired when making a call recording application for Android.
I know the official Android SDK has not allowed using VOICE_CALL. So my recording is based entirely on the MIC source.
I tried the Android NDK but I also fell into a deadlock.
Someone, please give me away. If you have the source code, it's great. Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that for a long time now (since API level 19?), recording voice calls has required a permission that only system apps can get. So what you're trying to do isn't really supported. Doesn't matter if you use the NDK or not.

Comment: I reading some one topic from stack. I known their sucessed when use NDK to create Call Recorder. But I was failed when create it. But I want to create it, so I will wait support from any one.

Comment: @HoàngGiang any update on this? I am also looking for the call record using NDK

Comment: No solution from now :((

Answer (score 3):

Android has officially blocked the SDK method since Marshmallow. After that a work around was introduced with the NDK to solve the problem. This seemed to work in android 6, 7 and 8. The NDK based approach is also blocked in Pie. So technically it is impossible to record calls.
[Source](https://piunikaweb.com/2018/08/14/android9pie-closes-all-doors-to-call-recording-sans-root-say-third-party-app-devs/)

Comment: Do you have any reference to getting started with `Call Recording` using `NDK`?

Comment: This might help you https://github.com/ViktorDegtyarev/CallRecLib

Answer (score 0):

Record a call in Android could be a strenuous work, this because not all Android version support the call recording.

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46298938/how-to-implement-call-recording-with-android-ndk?rq=1)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862857/how-to-record-call-in-android-is-it-possible?rq=1)

[Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631588/why-cant-we-record-an-incoming-call-in-an-android-application?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Any answer. Because I was use all question you comment. But it not good for my idea. I want create Call recorder in C++ of NDK. I think it can help for me!

Comment: Did u made it? Coz im curently doing on same app :)